# Unable to deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku, but it asks me to add the updated `Gemfile.lock` to version control. The log is:

```
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick... done
remote: -----> ImageMagick app detected
remote: -----> Install ImageMagick
remote: -----> Extracting ImageMagick /app/tmp/cache/imagemagick.tar.gz => /tmp/build_397f5ab6d29af054b826b2a1303ae32b/vendor
remote: -----> Writing policy file
remote: -----> Updating environment variables
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * source:
```

It asks me to add the updated Gemfile.lock, but still doesn't work when I delete it and generate a new one. I have tried the solutions mentioned on various S.O. questions, but none of them work for me.
Also, I have staged and committed.

Comment: looks like you have not uploaded all the message of deployment process. in addition to that if you can add heroku log, it will be easier to evaluate problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not committed your Gemfile.lock to the git. make sure you committed it. if you want to deploy on Heroku Gemfile.lock is required

Steps:
1) Git status

2) it will show you modified: Gemfile.lock

3) git commit Gemfile.lock -m "comment"

4) git push origin "branch name"

5) try to deploy with this branch.

Comment: Try with bundle update and then commit ur Gemfile.lock

Comment: Yes, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `bundle install` this will generate gemfile.lock automatically. 
Gemfile.lock is file which keep the record of all the version you and what are the gems you have installed it will be generated when you first run `bundle install` and when you run same command in future it will first look in gemfile.lock to check what version and what are gem to be installed.

once you run `bundle install` then try all command to deploy your app

```
git init

git add . 

git commit -am "some comment"

git push heroku master
```